# Django: How to declare a project wide template context processor?

Tags: python, django

I can declare context processors that will be enabled globally but can organize them based on apps like `"myapp.context_processors.remote_ip"` but I want to create a project specific `context_processors.py`. How we would declare a project wide `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` entry?

From docs and other stackoverflow question all entries were listed in the format `"<app_name>.<context_processors_file_name>.<function_name>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template context processors are not application-wise, but module wise. This means: the module must be reachable by PYTHON_PATH. If you have such `context_processors` python file alongside your apps, you can safely include any context processor inside: `context_processors.AContextProcessor`.

Consider the default value as an example:

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

`django` is not an app in your project, but a module. `django` is reachable by python path like that. So can your `context_processors` file be reachable as well.